# using value from dropdown box as input to sql

Tags: jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebook with dropdown box and sql
I am using a dropdown box that receives the values from %sql select... 
I display drop.value and it indicates 'SYSCAT' = ok
now I need to use this drop.value as an input to another %sql

```
sql select .. from table where col=$drop.value
```

in this case the value is supplied but I need the quotes

```
sql select ..from table where col1='SYSCAT'
```

how can this be done ? any idea
thanks for all update, Best regards, Guy